# Differences between two java process instances

Tags: java, ant, firewall

I have a java TCP server `TCPEchoServer` on my Windows computer and a client `TCPClient` on a remote Linux computer.

When I launch `TCPEchoServer` from the command line everything works fine. But when I launch it from Ant then the client cannot establish the connection to my server.

When I turn off the Windows firewall then everything works fine in both cases (command line and Ant). I don't specify any proxy settings via ANT_OPTS or via command line.

When I start my `TCPClient` locally it connects correctly in both cases as well.

In Java configuration panel I have "Use browser settings" option.

I want to know how can I detect the differences between instances of java process launched from the command line and from Ant.

I printed out the env and java System properties. Everything seems to be the same. What else can I print out to see the difference?

Here is the java code and Ant script.

The server:

```
import java.net.*; 
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 

public class TCPEchoServer extends Thread { 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 


        for(String prop : System.getProperties().stringPropertyNames()) {
            System.out.println(prop + "=" + System.getProperties().getProperty(prop));
        }
        Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
        for (String name : env.keySet()) {
            System.out.format("%s=%s%n", name, env.get(name));
        }

        ServerSocket serverSocket = null; 
        int port = -1;
        if(args.length < 1) {
            System.out.println("java TCPEchoServer port");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        port = new Integer(args[0]).intValue();

        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port); 
        while(true) {
            final Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try{
                        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()); 
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); 
                        String inputLine; 
                        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) { 
                            System.out.println("received:" + inputLine);
                            out.writeBytes(inputLine.toUpperCase() + "\n");
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {
                        System.err.println("Exception:" + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }.start(); 
        }

    }

}
```

The client

```
import java.net.*; 
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 

public class TCPClient { 

    public static void detectProxy(String host, int port) {
        System.out.println("detecting proxies");
        List proxyList = null;
        try {
            proxyList = ProxySelector.getDefault().select(new URI("socket://" + host + ":" + port));
        } 
        catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        if (proxyList != null) {
            for (Object p : proxyList) {
                java.net.Proxy proxy = (java.net.Proxy)p;
                InetSocketAddress addr = (InetSocketAddress) proxy.address();
                System.out.println(proxy.type() + ((addr == null)? "No Proxy": "host:" + addr.getHostName() + ", port" + addr.getPort()));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 

        ServerSocket serverSocket = null; 
        int port = -1;
        if(args.length < 2) {
            System.out.println("java TCPClient host port");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        port = new Integer(args[1]).intValue();
        detectProxy(args[0], port);

        Socket socket = new Socket(args[0], port);
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()); 
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); 
        out.writeBytes("Hi there!\n");
        System.out.println("got back:" + in.readLine());
        socket.close();
    }

}
```

The ant script

```
<project name="server" default="run">
    <target name="run" >
        <java fork="true" spawn="false" classname="TCPEchoServer" >
            <arg value="4444" />
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="." />
            </classpath>
        </java>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Use tool like TcpView and check if you can see an open socket in the ant case. (http://technet.microsoft.com/de-ch/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx)

Comment: If you are using Java on Windows ANT may execute a different java.exe instance that has a different set of firewall rules.

Comment: What do you see in the task manager? Could it be the case that ant is seen as `ant.exe` and java is seen as `java.exe`. And whilst Java is a trusted program, Ant is not. So you may need to add a firewall exception for Ant.

Comment: @Boris the Spider: In both cases I see java.exe

Comment: @Robert: According to java.library.path both use the same java.

Comment: When you start the server, open a windows command shell, and type "netstat -an" - can you then see port 4444 in the listening state?

Comment: @Greycon: yes, I see the  port in both cases: cmd line and Ant

Comment: Can you add print out some debug line just before your serverSocket.accept() call, and just after it? And then one just inside the run() method? I see you are catching Exception() - you might try catching Throwable() just in case...

Comment: @Greycon: I added debug lines. It waits for accept(). It prints a message before but not the message after

Comment: Does it work if you spawn() in ant, instead of fork() ?

Comment: @Greycon: Yes, I tried both options

Comment: OK. The only thing I can think of is that in the command line case, cmd.exe is creating the JVM process (java.exe), and the firewall sees cmd.exe as the "owning" process; whereas in the second case the firewall sees ant.exe as the owning process. Total guess. Can you turn on monitoring on the windows firewall and see if it gives you a clue?

Comment: Could you install wireshark on your windows machine, and set it to monitor port 4444? This way we could at least tell if anything at all gets in on port 4444... maybe it's the outbound leg that's causing the issue.

Comment: @Greycon Yes, I can see in the log that the firewall dropped the request 2014-08-15 15:31:23 DROP TCP xx.x.xx.xx yy.y.yyy.yyy 19371 4444 60 S 1376991313 0 5840 - - - RECEIVE

Comment: Interesting. What happens if you add a rule to open port 4444 on your firewall? (As in, general open, not for specific programs). I'm off to get a sandwich, but will be back in 20. I'm no expert in Winows firewall, it's just your problem is intriguing :-)

Comment: @Greycon I tried to add a rule but without success. Something is wrong. Sorry I have to go. I'll continue my investigation on Monday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the solution was to enable the firewall for all java platform binaries

[image]